# Rspec: How to test that on every each loop class method is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd

I am currently trying to test a portion of code in my rails worker class as shown below(simplified version);

```
class SenderWorker
   include Sidekiq::Worker
   sidekiq_options :retry => 5

   def perform(current_user_guid)
      Rails.logger.info "Starting for user_guid: #{current_user_guid}"
      user = User.find_by!(guid: current_user_guid)
      team = Team.find_by!(uuid: user.team.uuid)
      profiles = team.profiles 
      profiles.each do |profile|
         SenderClass.new(profile,
                         user).send(User::RECALL_USER)
      end
      Rails.logger.info "Finishing for user_guid: #{current_user_guid}"
   end
end
```

The tests that I have written are these and they are passing;

```
context 'when something occurs' do
  it 'should send' do
    sender = double("sender")
    allow(SenderClass).to receive(:new).with(user_profile, current_user) { sender }
    expect(sender).to receive(:send)
    expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).exactly(2).times

    worker.perform(user.guid)
  end
end
```

However, I am not testing for all calls. Is there a way to ensure that I test for everything called in the `each do` loop. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test that `:send` is received an expected amount of times.

But I'd suggest you to simplify the test by using a class method to encapsulate those chained methods. Something like:

```
def self.profile_send(profile, user)
  new(profile, user).send(User::RECALL_USER)
end
```

Then:

```
def perform(current_user_guid)
  Rails.logger.info "Starting for user_guid: #{current_user_guid}"
  user = User.find_by!(guid: current_user_guid)
  team = Team.find_by!(uuid: user.team.uuid)
  profiles = team.profiles 
  profiles.each do |profile|
    SenderClass.profile_send(profile, user)
  end
  Rails.logger.info "Finishing for user_guid: #{current_user_guid}"
end
```

And now you can test that SenderClass receives `:send_profile` X times.

You can then add a test for SenderClass.send_profile if you really want to test the `new` and the `send` method calls, but then you can test that once, outside a loop and both tests will cover what you want.